NetworkManager - Can I disable the default Wired connection 1 and use a predefined file as default?
I have two files, eth0-static and eth0-dhcp, for my NetworkManager defined and I want that the NetworkManager uses one these files as default instead. The file selection depends on DHCP enabled or not. How can I tell NetworkManager to use one of these files instead of creating Wired connection 1? Or does it make more sense to rename the existing files?

NetworkManager is a service, and you can outright disable and not use it.  And configure everything without using NetworkManager.

NOTE: depending on your Linux distribution version (which in turn influences NetworkManager version) support for ifcfg files may be depreciated or maybe even disabled (not sure if disabled option was already rolled out).
To check where your current network connections are stored use:
nmcli -f NAME,DEVICE,FILENAME connection show

Example output for the legacy configuration:
NAME    DEVICE  FILENAME
ens192  ens192  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192

Example output for the new configuration:
NAME    DEVICE  FILENAME
ens192  ens192  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ens192.nmconnection

1. Setting chosen connection as default and disabling automatic connection creation.
Assuming you're on the older version still defaulting to ifcfg files - according to the NetworkManager's interface configuration manual all you have to do is prepend ifcfg- to the names of your files (as NetworkManager expects them to follow the naming convention ifcfg-* to manage them properly) and put them to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ (/etc/network/interfaces for Debian, or wherever your distribution puts those - see nmcli output on your machine).
Then, to activate the chosen connection and make it persistent:
nmcli connection load /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0-static
nmcli connection up eth0

Note: in case of Error: unknown connection use nmcli connection show to see the correct interface name.
To check if persistence is working you can issue:
nmcli connection show
nmcli connection show --active

And to be completely sure - simply reboot the machine :)
This should be enough to use chosen connection and to prevent NetworkManager from  creating Wired connection 1, but if you want to be safer you can always explicitly disallow such behavior by modifying
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:
vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

add/modify:
[main]
no-auto-default=*

2. Forcing NetworkManager to use manual IP configuration if DHCP fails.
This one's a little tricky (but still doable) if you insist on using ifcfg files - I'll create an easier example first (using new keyfiles) and add the legacy version if requested.
The new syntax allows us to create a single file, assuming your interface is eth0 naming convention requires eth0.nmconnection name, created in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections:
vim /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0.nmconnection

Create the following sections inside the file (discard my comments marked # ---->):
[connection]
id=eth0
uuid= # ----> [[same as in ifcfg file, >> nmcli connection show << to find]]
type=ethernet
interface-name=eth0

[ethernet]

[ipv4]
method=auto
dhcp-timeout=10
dhcp-fallback=true
address1=192.168.1.100/24,192.168.1.1  # ----> example, obviously use yours
dns=1.1.1.1;8.8.8.8; # ----> 1.1.1.1 - cloudflare (my fav), 8.8.8.8 - google, use whatever you like
may-fail=false

[ipv6]
method=ignore

NOTE: "/24" in address1 variable above is the netmask in CIDR notation (/24 is an equivalent to 255.255.255.0), and 192.168.1.1 is the gateway.
Save the file. Activate the connection and make it persistent:
nmcli connection load /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0.nmconnection
nmcli connection up eth0

Test for persistence like in the first paragraph.

Okay I can handle DHCP and static in one file. My Linux is a Yocto based Linux so I need a way to use eth0.nmconnection as default for the build. So the question is how can I replace the UUID in this connection file with the UUID from the system. Maybe via a shell script?

@Kampi I just tested on Rocky Linux 9.2: if you shut down, add a new interface and boot up NetworkManager DOES NOT automatically create connection file, but IT CREATES a new device with an UUID - shown in nmcli connection show. All you have to do is replace the uuid= in the .nmconnection file with the correct one and then activate. Example one-liner: sed -i "s/^uuid=.*/uuid=$(nmcli connection show | awk '/^Wired connection 1/ {print $4}')/" /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0.nmconnection
